# Can I run queued lambdas with pre-defined arguments?

Tags: java, lambda, queue, functional-interface

I'm looking to add lambdas to a queue to be run when the queue is polled, using the arguments passed to them when they were added to the queue. Something like below:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Movement {

Deque<Movement> movementDeque = new ArrayDeque<>();

    void move(MovementType type);

}

...

public void addToQueue(Direction direction){

    MovementType type = switch (direction) {
        case LEFT -> MovementType.TURN_LEFT;
        case RIGHT -> MovementType.TURN_RIGHT;
        case UP -> MovementType.FORWARD;
        case DOWN -> MovementType.BACKWARD;
    }
    
    Movement.movementDeque.offer((m) -> subject.move(type));

}

...
               
Movement.movementDeque.poll(); // Running the lambda later
```

Is this possible? None of what I've attempted so far seems to allow me to invoke lambdas using the arguments passed to them when they were defined. Feel like I'm misunderstanding something pretty fundamental here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think its possible to store a lambda with specific paramaters (since remember, a lambda is essentially just a shorthand method), what you could do though, is change the move method to not take any arguments

```cs
public interface Movement {
    void move();
}
```

And then you can simply queue the move method and invoke it like so

```cs
public void addToQueue(Direction direction){

    MovementType type = switch (direction) {
        case LEFT -> MovementType.TURN_LEFT;
        case RIGHT -> MovementType.TURN_RIGHT;
        case UP -> MovementType.FORWARD;
        case DOWN -> MovementType.BACKWARD;
    }
    
    Movement.movementDeque.offer(() -> subject.move(type));

}
```

```cs
Runnable movement = movementDeque.poll();
movement.run();
```

Which should achieve the same result you are expecting

Comment: Small typo: the last statement should be `movement.run();`

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I'm wondering what I'm missing: if we've removed all parameters from move(), how are we then able to pass it 'type' as an argument in the line Movement.movementDeque.offer(() -> subject.move(type));?

Comment: Its getting type from the code above, then creating the function

public void Move(){
    subject.move(MovementType.TURN_LEFT)
}

And adding to the queue, so whenever the function is invoked, it will still maintain the type you added at that time

Comment: Thanks again! I understand how the example works, but still aren't sure how we can pass move() an argument now that we've removed all parameters from it. I simply get this on compile:


java: method move in interface Movement cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found:    MovementType

Comment: Have you changed the interface to represent the changes?

Comment: Ah, I'm on the same page now - my addToQueue() method is elsewhere in the codebase, but your solution works provided I encapsulate everything in the Movement interface. I should've made that clearer in my original question. Cheers for bearing with me!

Comment: @Xry0s0 it’s not really encapsulated when you define the `Deque` variable in an interface. Variables declared in an interface are automatically `public static final` (so they’re not “variables” but named constants). You should separate the queue from the interface.